# Alembic - How do I get the sql script of a single revision?

Tags: alembic

I'm trying to get the SQL script generated from an alembic revision, but when I run:

```
alembic upgrade head --sql
```

It outputs the SQL of **all revisions**, and because there's a breaking revision in the middle (I haven't figured out why yet), I can't get the script from that point on. Moreover, I only want the SQL script of the last revision.

Is there a parameter to get that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After some time trying to figure it out, and reading [the docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/offline.html#getting-the-start-version), you can obtain the SQL of a single or multiple specific revisions by specifying `start:end` in the command line:

```
 alembic upgrade <previous>:<current> --sql
```

It will even output the update to the `alembic_version` table.

The same works with `downgrade`:

```
 alembic downgrade <current>:<previous> --sql
```

Answer (score 0):

`alembic upgrade <revision_name> --sql`

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when I was trying to get the sql script downgrade to the end.

```bash
(env)# alembic downgrade -1 --sql
ERROR:alembic.util.messaging:downgrade with --sql requires <fromrev>:<torev>
  FAILED: downgrade with --sql requires <fromrev>:<torev>
```

The case is quite rare. Maybe someone will be useful.
If you need to get a SQL and only 1 revision, then you can do this:

```bash
alembic downgrade 6a68657325e7:-1 --sql
```